# About a identity in probability theory.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, and $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of subsets in $\Omega$ such that:

i) $A_n \in \mathcal{F} \hspace{0.5cm} \forall n=1,2,...$

ii)$A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq ...$

Show that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)=P \left ( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right )$$

First I tried to prove it by induction, but I'm not convinced that is the proof.
Then I remembered the limit definition for sequences:

$L$ is the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ if $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exist a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>k$ occurs 
$\left |a_n-L \right|<\epsilon$

In this case $ \left |P(A_n)- P \left (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right )\right|<\epsilon$ but i can't see how to obtain that $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\bigcap A_j=\varnothing$, that is $A_n\downarrow \varnothing$. Set $B_n = A_n-A_{n+1}$ for $n$. Then the set $B_n$ are disjoint and belong to $\mathscr{F}$ and their union is $A_1$. Also their union for $n\ge m$ is $A_m$ for each $m$.  Then

$$P(A_1)=\sum P(B_n)<+\infty$$

Since the series converges. Given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $m$  such that for all $j\ge m$ we have

$$0\le P(A_j)\le P(A_m)= \sum_{n\ge m} P(B_n)<\epsilon$$

Therefore $P(A_n)\to 0$.

If $\bigcap A_j\not=\varnothing$. Set $\big\{A_n-\bigcap A_j\big\}_n$ so is a sequence of elements in the sigma algebra and also $\{A_n-\bigcap A_j\}\downarrow \varnothing$, using the above result we have

$$\lim_n P\left(A_n-\bigcap A_j\right) =0$$

But since $P$ is a finite measure. Then

$$\lim_n P(A_n)= P\left(\bigcap A_j\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $\;B\supseteq C\;$, then $\;C = B\cap C\;$.

So then $A_n = ....$

Comment: Yep, i did that, but I'm not convinced because the limit to infinity.

Comment: The limit isn't obscure.  The probability function is a measure over $\langle \Omega,\mathcal F\rangle$ so: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathsf P(A_n) = \mathsf P(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n)$ as long as $\forall n{\in}\Bbb N^+\; A_n{\in}\mathcal F$, which you have.